# Previsualizar datos Select HTML

Tags: php, html, html5, php8

En un formulario hecho con PHP he incluído un Select, el select muestra todos los valores de un vector y POSTea según la selección un ID que está incluído en otro vector, del siguiente modo:

```html
<label for="trabajador">Trabajador*:</label>
        <select name="trabajador" id="trabajador" style="width: 100%" required>
      <?php
        for($j = 0; $j <= count($trabajadores)-1; $j++){
          echo '<option value="'.$id_trabajadores[$j].'">'.$trabajadores[$j].'</option>';
        }
      ?>
    </select>
```

Esto me muestra una lista de trabajadores y según el que escoja me manda su id correspondiente.

Pongamos que tengo un tercer vector con el año de nacimiento de cada trabajador, de modo que el índice $j introducido en los tres vectores me aporta su nombre, su id y su año de nacimiento.

¿Puedo de algún modo mostrar en vivo en la web el año de nacimiento del empleado seleccionado? Es decir, que mientras estoy completando el formulario, al seleccionar un empleado al lado me muestre su año de nacimiento y al seleccionar otro cambie, eso sin enviar el formulario, sino durante el proceso de rellenar los campos.

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias formas de abordar este tema. Una de ellas podría ser la siguiente. Supongamos que tu fichero php es el siguiente

```
<html lang="es">
<body>

    <label for="trabajador">Trabajador*:</label> (<span id="id_anno"></span>)
        <select name="trabajador" id="trabajador" style="width: 100%" required>
      <?php
        for($j = 0; $j <= count($trabajadores)-1; $j++){
          echo "<option value='$id_trabajadores[$j]' anno='$anno[$j]'>$trabajadores[$j]</option>";
        }
      ?>
    </select>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

He puesto un **span** después del label para mostrar el año entre paréntesis.

A cada **option** le he añadido un atributo **anno** al que le asigno el año de vector **anno**

Por último, incluyo una llamada en el html generado para que se cargue un script llamado **script.js**

Adicionalmente, tendremos que crear ese fichero **script.js**. Yo lo he hecho con el siguiente código

**script.js**

```
document.getElementById('trabajador').addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    var anno = document.getElementById("id_anno");
    anno.innerHTML = event.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex].getAttribute('anno');
});
```

Como ves, cada vez que cambia el valor del select se llama al Listener, que obtiene la referencia al span con id **id_anno** y en su interior meto el valor del atributo **anno** del option seleccionado

**NOTAS**

1. He modificado un poquito el *echo* para que sea más legible
2. He supuesto que el vector en el que están los años se llama anno
3. Tampoco he tenido en cuenta que al cargar la página, el primer año
   no se lee. Lo he hecho para que el código quede más simple y se
   entienda mejor. Te dejo a ti la tarea de arreglar esto (es fácil)